# Windows Phone Toolkit CustomMessageBox long content scrolling

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-toolkit

In my project (**windows Phone 8 C#/XAML .NET 4.5 Application**) I'm using **Windows Phone Toolkit**.

While using CustomMessageBox, I've run into a problem when I use the CustomMessageBox for long text.

here is an example:

```
 CustomMessageBox box = new CustomMessageBox();
 box.content = "some really some really some really some really some really some really some really some really some really some really some really some really some really some really long text";
 box.Show();
```

And the text isn't wrapped or scrollable. So I tried Adding it into textblock:

```
CustomMessageBox box = new CustomMessageBox();
TextBlock txtblck = "some really some really some really some really some really some really some really some really some really some really some really some really some really some really long text";
txtblck.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
box.content = txtblck;
box.Show();
```

So finally, the text is wrapping as i need, but there is still another problem. How to make it scrollable - for example when you have a really long text - some long notice or legal agreement et cetera...

What should I do? I tried adding the textblock into ScrollViewer, but it does not work. I can scroll a bit, but it does not stay scrollable and when i stop trying to scroll down it returns to the starting position.

example:

```
 ScrollViewer viewer = new ScrollViewer();

 TextBlock txtInfo = new TextBlock();
 txtInfo.Text = "some long text here.....";
 txtInfo.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;

 viewer.Content = txtInfo;

 CustomMessageBox Box = new CustomMessageBox();
 Box.Content = viewer;
 Box.Show();
```

**How can i make the long text/content scrollable? Should I use another solution?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a fixed value for the height

```
ScrollViewer viewer = new ScrollViewer() { Height = 500 /* fixed Height */ };

TextBlock txtInfo = new TextBlock();
txtInfo.Text = @"some long text here.....";
txtInfo.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;

viewer.Content = txtInfo;


CustomMessageBox Box = new CustomMessageBox();
Box.Content = viewer;
Box.Show();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I tried setting it to some ridiculously high value (1500 for example) it didn't work, but when i set it to something smaller then what the fullscreen messagebox had left (cca 600px - i set it to 300) it started working :)